# How to implement GooglePlay TabBar in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Before everyone start posting link to some beginner UI tutorial video, please know that this is a known issue and I am looking if there’s a workaround for this. If you do not know, please do not attempt to answer.

This is the link to this bug. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17518

I have tried using NestedScrollView with sliverappbar to implement the hiding AppBar animation when scrolling animation but it is not as smooth as I expected when I scroll up. You can try out the behaviour in GooglePlay on android phone.

anyone has any solution or workaround for this?

If you look at the animation in Material.IO, the AppBar collapse and appear smoothly upon scrolling
https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-components%2Fassets%2F1cx_CQC_pYOeAxmJAoEIjGnZNAWQzz-O1%2Ftabs-scrolling-1.mp4

Comment: Use SliverAppBar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9C5KMJKluE

Comment: @MuhammadFarhan read title before attempt to answer, question isn't related to native development

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at the question already asked on StackOverflow [Flutter TabBar and SliverAppBar that hides when you scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187332/flutter-tabbar-and-sliverappbar-that-hides-when-you-scroll-down)

Comment: This is a known bug. I'm finding a workaround this. If you are new to Flutter, you will not know what I am talking about.

Comment: I know what you are talking about, but right now I also haven't got any workaround for this.