# How to make a top tab bar with CupertinoSliverNavigationBar Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I use CupertinoSliverNavigationBar, how can I add a tab bar below the title that is fixed to scroll?

My current code :

```
class SearchView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchViewState createState() => _SearchViewState();
}

class _SearchViewState extends State<SearchView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(width: 0.0, color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF)),
              leading: Material(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: Icon(
                    IconData(
                      0xe904,
                      fontFamily: 'icomoon',
                    ),
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 25.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              largeTitle: Text('Discover'),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Like on the attached picture :

[image: Example]

Of course, if there is a solution that works without the Cupertino widgets, but that still respects the design, I'm interested.

Comment: You want "Search" and "Recent" to be fixed ?

Comment: @BabC Exactly, I want the search and Recent to be fixed just below the app bar when scrolling

Comment: Can you provide your current code ? Basically you have to make scrollable only the Search and Recent part. Not the all page.

Comment: I have added my current code for more info

Comment: Here is same type of Question answered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291801/6449750

Comment: @HardikVaghani It's not really what I want to do. I've already tried it but it doesn't suit me. I really want to keep my Large Title widget in the CupertinoSliverNavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [Tab View](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tab-views),
then you can use CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl placed in the middle of CupertinoPageScaffold.

[Link on Flutter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tab-views)