# How to hide app bar while scrolling up but shows up when scrolling down?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to achieve the behavior as we see in android WhatsApp and advised tab behavior in material design, check suggestion [here](https://material.io/components/tabs#behavior) and the video
[here](https://kstatic.googleusercontent.com/files/2e3a3d377ed4ad0cc985e4e855f71dc2f418581deeca6dfdbddbfcaba815c912c58dfddb365cbc8fd9d34dc1f31ebbbbfea597b68fe1f4e0ecefffdcbff4fd4b). When i scroll down, I want the tab bar to be visible but the app bar to hide, this behaviour can be seen on the medium android app as well.

I saw there was an earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948252/hide-appbar-on-scroll-flutter), but it did not work for me.

I've tried several approaches but the nested scroll view doesn't work for me.

```
 return DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child:Scaffold(
    body: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
         SliverAppBar(
            title: Text("Application"),
            floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            snap: true,
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: <Tab>[
               Tab(text: "T"),
               Tab(text: "B"),
              ], // <-- total of 2 tabs
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
         RandomWords(),
         RandomWords(),
        ], 
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

and tried this as well,

```
Scaffold(
   body: NestedScrollView(
     controller: _scrollViewController,
     headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
       return <Widget>[
         SliverAppBar(
           title: Text("N"),
           pinned: true,
           floating: true,
           forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
           //snap: true,
           bottom: TabBar(
             tabs: <Tab>[
              Tab(text: "T"),
              Tab(text: "B"),
             ],
             controller: _tabController,
           ),
         )
       ];
     },
     body: TabBarView(
       children: <Widget>[
         RandomWords(),
         RandomWords(),
       ],
       controller: _tabController,
     ),
   ),
 ),
);
```

My code is available [here](https://pastebin.com/we0HX77j).

Is there any reason the `NestedScrollView` might not work?

Comment: could you add your code which you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SliverList and SliverAppBar

Comment: try to set floating: false, pinned: false, snap: false

Comment: What's happening? Can you link a video?

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu There seems to be an issue with my widget that i'm loading in the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: new Scaffold(
        body: new NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              new SliverAppBar(
                title: Text("Application"),
                floating: true,
                pinned: true,
                snap: true,
                bottom: new TabBar(
                  tabs: <Tab>[
                    new Tab(text: "T"),
                    new Tab(text: "B"),
                  ], // <-- total of 2 tabs
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                  child: Text(
                'T Tab',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              )),
              Center(
                  child: Text(
                'B Tab',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: So while this itself works simply with the text in the tabs, when i try load my own widget it doesnt work with the scroll anymore

Comment: The basic behavior is widgets shows a list to load a json file and when someone clicks on an entry in the list, I navigate them to a new page.