# TabBar in the middle of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, tabcontrol, tabbar

I'm trying to put a TabBar in the middle of the screen to make a personal area view. Every time I run the code its jumps me up an exception.
The problem comes in the Tabbar the part above is just the name of the user and the Avatar but when I try to put the appbar it throws me this "throw constraintsError;"

Here is the source code which I use to make the view:

```
class PersonalArea extends StatelessWidget {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String _viewSelector = "personalData";

    late Color color = Colors.white;

    return new Scaffold(

        body: StoreConnector<AppState, PersonalAreaViewModel>(
            onInit: (store) {
              store.dispatch(new GetPersonalAreaAction());
            },
            converter: (store) => PersonalAreaViewModel.fromStore(store),
            builder: (context, viewModel) => Column(children: [
                  Stack(children: [
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 4),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                            child: Column(
                               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,children: [
                              Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      avatar(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                    child: edit(),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              //Avatar&Edit
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                                    child: generateStyleText(
                                        "${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.displayName}",
                                        color.primary75,
                                        FontWeight.w700,
                                        0,
                                        16,
                                        0),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              //Name
                            ]), //MainColumn
                          ),
                          DefaultTabController(
                              length: 3,
                              child: Container(
                                child: Column(
                                 
                                  children: [
                                    TabBar(
                                      tabs: [
                                        Tab(
                                          text: "Experiencia",
                                        ),
                                        Tab(
                                          text: "Area",
                                        ),
                                        Tab(
                                          text: "pedro",
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: TabBarView(
                                        children: [
                                          Text('people'),
                                          Text('Person'),
                                          Text("data"), 
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ))
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ])
                ])));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `DefaultTabController` with `Expanded`

Comment: Same exception.

Comment: can you share the exact exception

Comment: 'Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.\n'
                'Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and '
                'constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. '
                'In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of '
                'vertical space in which to expand.',

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54148475/6882568)