# Make SliverAppBar scrollable when TabBarView child is scrolled

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have home screen with bottom navigation consist of two items which all have ListView inside with infinite list and I want SliverAppBar to be scrollable when user scrolls in one of the list.
Here is what I have so far

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: new Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                snap: false,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                expandedHeight: 160.0,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  title: Text('Title'),
                ),
              ),
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: <Widget>[Items(), Activities()], //THESE HAVE LIST VIEW IN EACH 
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

And here is code of one of TabBarView children.

```
class Items extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> itemsWidgets = List.from(getItemsList()
        .map((Item item) => createItemWidget(context, item)));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: itemsWidgets,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ListTile createItemWidget(BuildContext context, Item item) {
    return new ListTile(
      title: Text(item.sender.name),
      subtitle: Text('10:30 am'),
    );
  }
}
```

How can SilverAppBar be scrollable when user scrolls in one of the list? Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [NestedScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html). There is an example in the api

Comment: I will have a look at it and bring feedback