# How to add Tabbar in SliverAppBar on Flutter?

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter

Can we add TabBar in our SliverAppBar?

Since SliverAppBar has the `bottom` property, I thought we can add Tabbar in our SliverAppBar, but the problem is TabBar needs DefaultTabbarController and DefaultTabbarController only works in Material Widget and SliverAppbar only works in Scaffold Body, not in my appbar, but I need my scaffold body to have TabView. What is the explanation?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear. Please post the code.

Comment: what i trying to do is i want make appbar that will hide when the users is scrolling, so i found on the internet if this can be achieve using SliverAppBar, but now i want add Tabbar to my SliverAppBar . So when users scrolling it will hide the SliverAppBar and left the TabbBar only just like in WhatsApp

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433885/sliverappbar-with-tabbar/50853287#50853287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you was asking. But I have only one problem, i.e., when I add a scrolling widget in TabView it doesn't produce the required result.

I have open [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19254).

Here is my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color tabColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark;
    TextStyle tabStyle = TextStyle(color: tabColor);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text("AppBar"),
              floating: true,
              primary: true,
              pinned: false,
            ),
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: TabBar(
                controller: tabController,
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      'Tab1',
                     style: tabStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      'Tab2',
                    style: tabStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
                body: TabBarView(
                  controller: tabController,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Scaffold(
                      body: Text('Tab One'),
                    ),
                    Scaffold(
                      body: Text('Tab Two'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Emulator Screen]

Comment: thanks for your answer , yeah as i mention in another answer i dont know why it doesnt work when i return listview. , I hope they fix it soon

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can add Tabbar inside SliverAppBar using NestedScrollView. You can also customise the appbar similar to that of whatsapp i.e floating appbar. Do make sure to add floatHeaderSlivers: true, in NestedScrollView for this.
[Link to working code](https://dartpad.dev/0955dcf876ba24619b86d49ec50788cc?)

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: CustomSliverAppbar(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomSliverAppbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomSliverAppbarState createState() => _CustomSliverAppbarState();
}

class _CustomSliverAppbarState extends State<CustomSliverAppbar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text(
                "WhatsApp type sliver appbar",
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              bottom: TabBar(
                  indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                  labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 16,
                  ),
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: [
                    Text("TAB A"),
                    Text("TAB B"),
                  ]),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            TabA(),
            const Center(
              child: Text('Display Tab 2',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class TabA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, child) => Divider(
          height: 1,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        itemCount: 30,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not answe with links only .Consider posting the code here

Comment: @ManosKounelakis Sorry for not adding the code, it is my 2nd answer. Will keep in mind to add code later on.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap `SilverAppBar`(which has `TabBar` as bottom) & `SilverFillRemaining`(wraps `TabBarView`) with `CustomScrollView`. Then set `CustomScrollView` as body of `Scaffold`. For this you need to create a `TabController`.

Full example here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SilverAppBarWithTabBarScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SilverAppBarWithTabBarState createState() => _SilverAppBarWithTabBarState();
}

class _SilverAppBarWithTabBarState extends State<SilverAppBarWithTabBarScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          new SliverAppBar(
            title: Text("Silver AppBar With ToolBar"),
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 160.0,
            bottom: new TabBar(
              tabs: [
                new Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                new Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                new Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
              ],
              controller: controller,
            ),
          ),
          new SliverFillRemaining(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: controller,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Tab 1"),
                Text("Tab 2"),
                Text("Tab 3"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer , i have question . why when i'm scrolling in my TabbBarView my appbar don't hide itself, isn't SliverAppBar created to fullfill those purpose ? or maybe i shhould add something here ?

Comment: Edit now the problem is myapbar wont react to my listvew scrolling, but its work well when my tabview just text, and second can i hide my appbar only without the bottom(tabbar) ,