# Custom Sliver app bar with background and tab bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create a custom sliver app bar that will shrink when the user starts scrolling. The extended app bar will have two distinct features:

1. Background Image
2. Tab Bar

[image]

Expected sliverappbar before scroll:

[image]

As, the user starts to scroll the appbar will become the default `AppBar` provided by flutter

This is what I have done till now. And the code is:

```
class _MerchantSliverAppbarState extends State<MerchantSliverAppbar> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: 200.0,
      pinned: true,
      floating: false,
      snap: false,
      leading: CustomBackButton(
        greyBackground: false,
      ),
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        background: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: size.width,
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/mock_background.png",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I tried to make the background Image take up the entire space, but for some reason I still have a little extra space(the blue zone).

I also have the red zone where the tab bar will be placed.

1. Why am I getting extra blue space and how can I solve it?
2. How can I implement a tab bar with this appbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your image is not fitted with your container, instead of that you use it as a background image:

```
Container(
              height: 200,
              width: size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                      'assets/images/test.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),

              ),
            )
```

For the tab bar, you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433885/sliverappbar-with-tabbar)

Comment: here is the complete source code https://gist.github.com/Jahidul007/69f750416e03992acee2d56c4d093a8c

Comment: Can I still use stack? The image will stay in the background. Their will be other stuff like some buttons: Follow button, more info button, merchant thumbnail etc on top of the image

Comment: got your point, i will try with stack and let you know

Comment: Remove the FlexibleSpaceBar, i hope solve your issue, please check out the updated answer https://gist.github.com/Jahidul007/69f750416e03992acee2d56c4d093a8c

Comment: hi, I updated my question. I understand your solution but I need something like I mentioned in my question

Comment: Adjust yourself as much as you need, SO for gives the idea not for the perfect solution, happy coding and check out from here https://gist.github.com/Jahidul007/69f750416e03992acee2d56c4d093a8c

Comment: yes I guess I can work out the rest by myself, thanks for the time

Comment: @FahimHoque you are welcome, happy coding